# JAVA - Trying to use a variable from inside an actionperformed outside the class

Tags: java, variables, actionlistener

I am trying to access the (double) percentage variable outside my actionPerformed while retaining the changes that it goes through.
it is a drop down menu, and an ok button you press. once you press it, it calculates a value for percentage, which then i want to use later on in the program.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
btn.addActionListener(
new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    String currentCountry = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    double percentage = 0.00;

        if(currentCountry.equals("Brazil") || currentCountry.equals("Argentina")) {
            cb2.removeAllItems();
            for(int i = 0; i < choicesSouthAmerica.length; i++) {
                cb2.addItem(choicesSouthAmerica[i]);
            }
        }

        else {

            cb2.removeAllItems();
            for(int i = 0; i < choicesEurope.length; i++) {
                cb2.addItem(choicesEurope[i]);
            }
        }

    btn.setEnabled(false);
    btn2.setEnabled(true);

        if(currentCountry.equals("Brazil") || currentCountry.equals("Argentina")){
                percentage = 1/5;
                System.out.println(percentage);
            }
        else{
                percentage = 1/8;
                System.out.println(percentage);
            }
        }
    } 

);
```

Thank you kindly

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example, **properly indented**, showing the problem. Explain what it is supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: i dont know why the indenting turned out like that, i tried pasting it, and using the ctrl k to indent it, but instead it turned out this way. I am just wondering how I can use the double percentage variable outside this method.

Comment: And I'm wondering how many methods exist in the code you posted, and where the variable is declared, and can't figure it out because the code is not properly indented.

Comment: It is declared inside the method, so you can't. But you can use a variable declared outside in your method.

Comment: even if i declare it outside the method, once inside the method there are changes made to it, i can't access the changes outside the method.

Comment: @JBNizet i know it is really ugly, im sorry about that, but the variable is declared inside actionPerformed, and i want to use it after that in the program, is there anyway? should i repost the code ?

Comment: As I said, post a complete, minimal example, properly indented, showing the problem. Explain what it is supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: i hope this helps, thank you

Comment: It's not complete, it's not minimal, it's not properly indented, it doesn't explain what it's supposed to do and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually need is just a static field (it can have whatever access modifiers you want). So something like this I think should work:

```
public class Test {

        static double d = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JButton b = new JButton("ASDF");
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    d = 5;
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: @newbievancouver If you liked my answer don't forget to flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the putClientProperty(Object,Object) and getClientProperty(Object) functions as follow :

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Ok");
    btn.putClientProperty("percentage",1.0);//or whatever initial value
    btn.addActionListener(arg0 -> {
        JButton source = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
        double per = (double)source.getClientProperty("percentage");
        per = (double)10/8;
        source.putClientProperty("percentage",per);
    });
    double percentage = (double)btn.getClientProperty("percentage");//or use it in any other object that has access to the btn object
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Java doesn't support closures, so you can not modify variables outside the scope of an anonymous class. But you can access final variables, so in principle you can do something like this:

```
class Percentage {
    double p;
}
final Percentage p = new Percentage();

btn.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // [...]
            p.p = 1/5;
            // [...]
        }
    }
);
```

Then you can access the updated percentage via `p.p` outside of your anonymous class. (Btw. is it really a "percentage" or in fact a ratio?)

But this doesn't seem very idiomatic for Java, so the clean solution is probably just to make a proper class with a private instance variable and a getter and use this instead of the anonymous class.